# Zenoss - Create Application Based Alert

Tags: alert, monitoring, zenoss

I am attempting to monitor a java-based application for running/not running status and alert based on that monitor within Zenoss.

The process class I have created works and correctly identifies the java processes is running, however, I seem unable to create an alert that will sound off when the process is killed.

To test, I have placed a test server in our production alerts category, which is tried and true, and killed the process. When testing the process class against that server, as stated, it correctly identifies the process is not running but does not send an alert. The process class has numerous devices it is monitoring, including the test server I am using.

Is there a specific trigger condition to use for a process class I have yet to find?

If anyone has any pointers I would greatly appreciate it. It seems like I need an event class of sorts or my trigger is incorrect but I have yet to figure it out.